# Returning value from ActiveCell.Column

Tags: excel, vba

Probably a noob question, but I am a noob, and i cant find the answer anywhere.

when I use this code:

```
Dim Startcell As Variant
Set Startcell = Cells(ActiveCell.Column)
```

I cant get "Startcell" to take the value from ActiveCell.Column. I can see that ActiveCell.Column has a value, but its not transfered to "Startcell"

If i change it to:

```
Dim Startcell As Variant
Set Startcell = ActiveCell.Column
```

I get an error saying that object is missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Column` is a long. That's why the second code block gives you an error. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement) on the `Set` statement. I don't understand what you're trying to do with `Cells(ActiveCell.Column)`. Maybe see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells).

Answer (score 0):

getting the column position of the current ActiveCell:

```
Dim Startcell As Long
Startcell = ActiveCell.Column
```